# How to delete line of a file with out writing to another file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I want to find a line in a text file and delete it.
Ex:

```
 aaa       aaa
 bbb   ->  ccc (bbb deleted)
 ccc
```

There is a example to do that but it writes to new file and rewrite. how to do that without writing to another file(also with out rewriting to same file also because it contains lot of data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only to do this is by writing a new file.

If you think about the file system, and how the file is stored on the hard drive. Most file systems will store the file as a sequential block on your hard drive. If you just remove those bytes from the file, then there would be an empty hole in the file. You would have to shift the bytes which are to the right of the bytes you removed, to the left in the file. Either way the file system is limiting you.

Instead you can try to minimize the number of times you write a new file. For example if you're making a word processor for large file, you can instead save a file which contains the edits the user made, and execute those commands after the user closes the file (and write the file only once).

Answer (score 0):

did you try to get the text file content to a string array variable?

here is a pseudo code how would I do that;

```
var your_text_content= txt file;
var your_new_text_content = your_text_content.replace("line you are looking for",""); 
txtfile = your_new_text_content;
```

Comment: In here also file is rewriting. i want to remove one line of a file without rewriting to another file or same file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  All software that has this feature copy the content of the file to a variable and delete the line and copy back the content where the line is deleted.

So you need to copy the content of the file.  Read line by line until you reach the line and delete it and save the content again.

This is how Notepad and other editors work.  That's why most of those editors only accepts files up to 1 GB. Because it takes time with huge files.

Hope this helps.

I will not post any code because you already said you found a solution for this.